# Function with multiple parameter is not working a expected

Tags: python

When I defined and applied the following function, it is not passing new "score" value to further codes.  Do you know why?

[image]

Comment: Please put the code inline into the question! Make sure everybody can copy'n'paste your code inorder to run it. Also, what do you observe? Your interpretation is that it is not passing something, but what do you actually see? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: int objects are immutable in python so if you change these values inside any function then that will not be reflected but list objects are mutable so it is changed inside function.